# Why does the max() function behave differently for two properties in this example?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

In the code below, the `height` and `width` of `div.greenBox` are both set with `max(40%,150px)`.

Viewed in the latest stable-release Chrome 79 for Windows 10, the `width` is computed as `150px` while the `height` is computed as `0`. **Why is that?**

Note: I am aware of other workarounds which could cause the outcome to be similar, such as `height:40%; min-height:150px;`, but would like to understand why the `max()` function acts differently in these two cases.

According to the [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max), the `max()` function

> takes one or more comma-separated expressions as its parameter, with the largest (most positive) expression value used as the value of the property to which it is assigned.

Even if the `40%` term computes to `0`, shouldn't `150px` be selected because it is more positive? Or if not, shouldn't the behavior for `width` be the same?

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wbtfiddle/p7Lzqn8m/3/

HTML core:

```css
div#mainContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /* vertical */
  justify-content: center;
  /* horizontal */
  text-align: center;
}

div.greenBox {
  height: max(40%, 150px);
  width: max(40%, 150px);
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainContainer">
  <div>
    Here is some sample text.
    <br>Its author would expect a green box to follow.
    <br>
    <div class="greenBox">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you check if the parent div is getting a proper explicit height ?

Comment: *Even if the 40% term computes to 0,* --> it computes to `auto` which create the issue and make the whole vale to compute to auto (0)

Comment: sinanspd: As seen in the linked JSfiddle, the parent div is getting a computed height in pixels.
@TemaniAfif An expanded version of your comment might make an Answer; it's still hard to tell how anything that is equivalent to 0 is less than 150px.

Comment: not really equivalent to 0, will add an answer (missing some accurate details not inside the Spec by the way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main issue is the use of percentage with `height` which in your case will fall to auto since there is no explicit height defined on the parent element:

> Specifies a percentage height. The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, **the value computes to 'auto'**.<sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#the-height-property)</sup>

You will basically have something like `max(auto,150px)` which is failling to `auto` not because `auto` is greater than `150px` but because the comparaison is invalid.

In your case `auto` will logicailly compute to `0` since your element is empty.

Here is more examples to better understand:

```css
.box>div {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: max(40%, 50px);
  width: max(40%, 50px);
  background: red;
}

.box {
  margin: 40px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>my height will <br>be the content height </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  the height will be 0
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="box" style="height:40px;">
  <div>my height will be 50px</div>
</div>

<div class="box" style="height:0px;">
  <div>my height will still be 50px</div>
</div>

<div class="box" style="height:200px;">
  <div>my height will be 80px</div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div style="position:absolute;"> My height will be 50px</div>
</div>
```

---

> shouldn't the behavior for width be the same?

We almost never have issue with percentage value inside width but both behave exactly the same and in case we cannot resolve the percentage value, it will also fail to auto.

Comment: Is `auto` always the largest in any comparison?  Is there documentation of that which can be linked to here?

Comment: @WBT no, there is no more comparaison involved. the Whole max() will fail to auto. You will not compare auto with px

Comment: The quote says "If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), *and this element is not absolutely positioned*..." but in this case the containing block **is** absolutely positioned.  Is there clearer documentation showing it still applies?

Comment: @WBT the containing block isn't position:absolute and even if it was the case, the element where you apply the height need to be position:absolute, not its containing block. Check the last case of my example

Comment: The containing block is div#mainContainer and `position:absolute` is on the fourth line of CSS.  The linked docs say *"Note that the height of the containing block of an absolutely positioned element is independent of the size of the element itself, and thus a percentage height on such an element can always be resolved."*

Comment: @WBT *and thus a percentage height on such an element can always be resolved* --> "on such element" refers to the positionned element and not its containing block

Comment: @WBT *The containing block is div#mainContaine* --> it's not, you have another nested div

Comment: Ah, my bad; I missed that.  Thanks for your help.